# property selectedIndex does not exists on type HTMLElement

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert some js files to using typescript in asp.net webforms.  The javascript works but it won't compile in ts because of the errors.  Here is the code

```
 var mDropDownID = arySecondTier[x];
 var DropdownList = (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lvCASec2_Detail_ctrl" + mDropDownID + "_ddlPoints"));
 var SelectedIndex = DropdownList.selectedIndex;
```

the error happens on the selectedIndex line.  From what i've read with typescript there is no selectedIndex on the HTMLElement, that i need to use a subtype of HTMLElement.  If that is the case i'm having problems finding what the name of that subtype would be.  If it's something else, well then i'd love to know what.

I've seen some who convert the DropDownList to , but my first thought is doesn't that go against the reason you want to use typescript.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to let the compiler that the `DropdownList` is a select element:

```
var DropdownList = (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lvCASec2_Detail_ctrl" + mDropDownID + "_ddlPoints")) as HTMLSelectElement;
 var SelectedIndex = DropdownList.selectedIndex; // no error
```

Also, you can do this:

```
`ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lvCASec2_Detail_ctrl ${ mDropDownID } _ddlPoints`
```

Instead of the string concatenation.

---

#### Edit

You know which type of element you need to have based on the actual element in the dom.
If you get a reference to a script element then it needs to be a `HTMLScriptElement`, if it's a div then `HTMLDivElement` and so on.

MDN is a great source for information, but in this case I'd just check the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts) (should be available from your IDE as well) to see what this element have.
For example the [HTMLScriptElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L10846) has:

```
interface HTMLScriptElement extends HTMLElement {
    async: boolean;
    charset: string;
    defer: boolean;
    event: string;
    htmlFor: string;
    src: string;
    text: string;
    type: string;
}
```

Comment: Great, so a little further down in my code I had this.  var SelectedText = DropdownList.options[DropdownList.selectedIndex].text; which gives me the error that HTMLElement doesn't have "text".  If i changed it to var SelectedText = (<HTMLScriptElement>DropdownList.options[DropdownList.selectedIndex]).text; the error goes away.  I guess my question is two fold then, is this the correct way to do it and how do i know what subtype to look in.  I looked under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement but there is a lot to go through there to try to find it. Is there a shortcut?

Comment: Check my revised answer